# quick way to add values to a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm having trouble with my code:

I want to end up with an array

```
[ 
  [ [a], [b], [c] ], 
  [ [d], [e], [f] ], 
  [ [g], [h], [i] ],
]
```

I've written

```
test = [][]

i = 0
j = 0
k = 'a'

while i < 3:
    while j < 3:
        test[i][j] = k
        j += 1
        k += 1
    i += 1

print(test)
```

Whats wrong with my code? (Its currently a syntax error)

Cheers

Comment: you're adding an integer to a string

Comment: test = [][] means nothing. That's two lists in a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code fails because

1. `[][]` this is not how we create 2D lists in python
2. you are incrementing `k` by 1 where `k` is a string and that is not allowed in python.

You can create two dimensional arrays with list comprehension, like this

```
test = [[[chr(i + 97)] for i in range(j * 3, j * 3 + 3)] for j in range(3)]
```

You can explicitly use two loops and [chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) function to create the characters corresponding to the ASCII values, like this

```
matrix = []
for j in range(3):
    row = []
    for i in range(j * 3, j * 3 + 3):
        row.append([chr(i + 97)])
    matrix.append(row)
print matrix
```

**Output**

```
[[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['e'], ['f']], [['g'], ['h'], ['i']]]
```

Comment: is it matrix.append([row]) or matrix.append(row)?

Comment: @user2977202 You wanted the data in third level, right? Thats why you need those square brackets, otherwise you don't need them.

Comment: I want 3 rows, the first containing [[a], [b], [c]], the second contining d,e and f in the same way and so on.

Comment: @user2977202 Yup. Thats what this program will produce. Please check the output section in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you just need that exact output, do this :

```
x = [[[a], [b], [c]], [[d], [e], [f]], [[g], [h], [i]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

a) This syntax is invalid. There is no such construct in python.

```
test = [][]
```

b) You cannot add element like this:

```
L = []
L[0] = 1
```

c) Also as GMPrazzoli pointed out, it is forbidden to add a number to a string

```
k = 'a'
#...
k += 1
```

First you need to create a list, then add **list** elements to the outer list.

Simple method:

```
[[b for b in range(3)] for a in range(3)]
```

Look up [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

I suppose you want characters in the list. For that you will need to use

- Python 2 docs: [ord](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), [chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr).
- Python 3 docs: [ord](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#ord), [chr](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#chr).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do quite a lot with number manipulation, why dont you use numpy library.

```
import numpy as Np

# create an array with required shape. 
# Mind you cannot create an empty array. 
# Best way to create a zero array or ones array.

shape_myarray=(3,3)

x=Np.zeros(shape_myarray)
y=Np.zeros(shape_myarray)

# You can index through the numpy array to update it with any value.
# Element wise addition is straight forward

z=Np.add(x,y) # make sure both the array is of same shape
```

Check the following links.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html
.